# Could not load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core after build the new source code (Pcapdot.net project)

Tags: c#

because Pcapdot.Net forum is not so active i will ask here.

Recently the developer of the project solved bug that causes crash after a few iteration each opening files but didn't publish new DLLs but said it would be possible to download the new source code and build it, so i did it.

i downloaded the source code and because it made with VS2010 and i am use VS2012 i installed VS2010 and build the code for x64 like my machine.
the application works fine and it crash after 509 iterations solved but after take my application to machine with VS2012 i cannot open it and it crash and after installed on this machine VS2010 it works so i double checked and on each machine without VS2010 it doesn't work and after VS2012 installations it works fine.

edit:

with the old DLLs its work fine even if i have on my machine only VS2012 and in both ways (works and not works) i have this warning:

**Warning  1   Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor**